# Create a view from multiple collections in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

View in SQL Server wants to create it in mongodb

```
CREATE VIEW memplog
AS
    SELECT
        recipient, originator, [text], create_date, sent_date   
    FROM
        [smslog_01042018]
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        recipient, originator,[text], create_date, sent_date
    FROM
        [smslog_02042018]
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        recipient, originator,[text], create_date, sent_date
    FROM
        [smslog_03042018]
```

Comment: You cannot do a UNION type of join with MongoDB as it's simply not supported by anything. This is a case where you really need to change your existing RDBMS structure to better suit the engine. Or indeed, stick with the RDBMS.

Comment: Indeed the UNION was probably a bad idea even in the RDBMS, and the data really should have been in the same table/collection with simply an extra field/property to denote it's source instead.